# How does a delegate remember it's parameters?

Tags: c#, parameters, delegates

Consider this code:

```
public ModelView(Model model) : this()
{
    Loaded += (object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) =>
    {
        DataContext = model;
    };
}
```

When the `Loaded` event runs again, the parameter `model` is present in memory, however it was never explicitly saved, was it?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://csharpindepth.com/articles/chapter5/closures.aspx) will be helpful.

Comment: It *was* saved, but the compiler did it behind the scenes.

Comment: Ok thanks, all clear, it is in the behind the scenes part - will delete the question.

Comment: You can read until the cows come home, and then still be surprised when you actually see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to @Avner's answer, this is what the C# compiler (sort of) generated for you under the covers:

```
public ModelView(Model model) : this()
{
    var closure = new AnonymousClass { _this = this, model = model };

    Loaded += closure.Loaded;
}

private class AnonymousClass
{
    public ModelView _this;
    public Model model;

    public void Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _this.DataContext = model;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

When you create an anonymous method or a lambda, the compiler creates a new class behind the scenes, with some internal name like `<ModelView>ctor_0` or something similar. This class has a method, which is the contents of your lambda, but it also has properties with *capture* the local state of function where the lambda is defined, and make it available to the lambda.

See the *Variable Scope in Lambda Expressions* section in the [Lambda Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) documentation on MSDN:

> The following rules apply to variable scope in lambda expressions:
>
> - A variable that is captured will not be garbage-collected until the delegate that references it becomes eligible for garbage collection.
>     Variables introduced within a lambda expression are not visible in the outer method.
> - A lambda expression cannot directly capture a ref or out parameter from an enclosing method.
> - A return statement in a lambda expression does not cause the enclosing method to return.
> - A lambda expression cannot contain a goto statement, break statement, or continue statement that is inside the lambda function if the jump statement’s target is outside the block. It is also an error to have a jump statement outside the lambda function block if the target is inside the block.